# View all table contain in 'HR' Account (Oracle 11g)

Tags: database, oracle, data-dictionary

```
SQL> select * from dba_hr_tables;
```

```
 select * from dba_hr_tables  
               * ERROR at line 1: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.
```

Please help me out to find all table contain in HR User ...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you're looking for all the tables owned by user `HR`.

If you have a user with system privileges, you could use the following:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM   dba_tables
WHERE  owner = 'HR'
```

If you don't. but have a user with privileges on `HR`'s tables, you could use `all_tables` instead of `dba_tables`:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM   all_tables
WHERE  owner = 'HR'
```

Alternatively, if you're able to logon as the `HR` user, you could do so and use:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM   user_tables
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the below to use your tables name. check your spelling as well!

```
SELECT *
    FROM tablename
```

Comment: i know  what you are trying to say ,,, i've already did it  ( Select * from  hr_table), i don't want to return single table ,, i want to return all the table (hr) Account contain. for Example (Select * from Dba_tables;) for selecting all tables from  Database.,, pls help me out to find it ... BTW Thnx for Response ..